# Showing if function is monotonic or strictly monotonic

Tags: calculus

I have a function and i know its derivative in the interval given is always greater than or equal to 0, f'(x)>=0. Therefore I believe I am correct in saying the function is monotonic in the interval as it is always increasing. However, how am I able to tell whether the function is strictly monotonic or not, from this information?

Comment: The function is strictly monotonic on an interval if $f'(x) > 0$ for all $x$ in that interval.

Comment: Yes but for this function f'(x)>=0. does the equal sign affect this?

Comment: Remember that $f'(x) > \implies f'(x) \geq 0$, i.e. $f'(x) > 0$ is a stronger condition than $f'(x) \geq 0$ in the same way strict monotonicity is stronger than monotonicity. So in order to assert strict monotonicity, you need to assert $f'(x) > 0$.